# OS X 10.9.4 Apple preview - can you rotate in inserted rectangle?

Tags: macos, preview

The updated version of Preview has so many features I can use it instead of the complicated photoshop. However I have found there is no way to rotate/angle an inserted rectangle or square. can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can only rotate an inserted shape by going to **Tools > Rotate Left/Right...**

Comment: This rotates the whole image not just the inserted shape

Comment: It's possible to rotate inserted shapes and annotations by holding the Command ⌘ key and rotating the selected element with two fingers on a trackpad: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/263964/122152